# Comparing two excel sheets with different sizes

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, openpyxl

I have two tables in excel, both have same headers but they have different sizes.
example:
name: x y
lname: zz xx
phone number: xxxxxx
salary:,,,,,

the two tables are the same but one is outdated, thus phone number and salary might change, at the same time I might have more/less employees.

I want to use python to be able to read both tables as dataframes, create a new dataframe that has the common values between the two tables, and be able to display both old and new values as different columns.
and preferably, I would like another table with the names of those that aren't common in both tables.
So far, I have been able to create a new table that just shows the differences between the two tables, but this method presumes that i have 2 tables of the same size and identical IDs.
I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: I think you should look to use pandas dataframes, and merge the old and new ones together. You should add examples of your tables and expected output to your questions (as text not images)

Comment: Show work done , approaches taken. Add examples of your table and expected output.

Comment: I do t have my laptop at the moment but here is what I have so far: I read both tables into dataframes, then identified x= df1==df2, row, col=np.where=true, then I create a new dataframe in which all values of both tables are presented. If the values are the same in both tables it just as them as is, if not it prints both showing the older one first. I will post what I have of my code later, but for now this is what I have. I'm having a problem with sorting both tables so that I have the rows with the same fname lname be in the same index so that the comparison is valid. Thanks 4 all answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the example dataframes I'm using, since I don't know what your dataframes look like:

```
df_1 = [["Abby", "Larsh", "609-661-6435", 75], ["Emma", "May", "609-333-4445", 100], ["Mark", "Winter", "609-228-7689", 90], ["Henry", "Melvin", "609-846-2365", 60], ["Angela", "McEvan", "609-123-1456", 105], ["Ethan", "Moser", "609-999-7584", 92]]
df_2 = [["Abby", "Larsh", "609-605-7777", 75], ["Emma", "May", "609-333-4445", 120], ["Mark", "Winter", "609-228-7689", 90], ["Angela", "McEvan", "609-122-4567", 115], ["Jack", "Sparrow", "609-669-8473", 80]]

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df_1, columns=["F_name", "L_name", "Phone_number", "Salary"])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df_2, columns=["F_name", "L_name", "Phone_number", "Salary"])
```

`df_1` is the outdated one and `df_2` is the current one. Abby's number changed, Emma's salary changed, both Angela's salary and phone number changed, Mark stayed same, Jack is new, Henry and Ethan left.

To get a merged dataframe, I change the names of the `Phone_number` and `Salary` columns in `df_1` to represent the old values:

```
df_1 = df_1.rename(columns={"Phone_number":"Old_phone_number", "Salary":"Old_salary"})
```

Then I can merge the dataframes to become `df_3`:

```
df_3 = pd.merge(df_2, df_1, how="outer", on=["F_name", "L_name"])
```

This merges by first and last name. Note that if you have multiple employees with the same name, this will cause problems. Merging by employee ID (if you have it) is much, much better.

I've got a rather convoluted and not-very-efficient way to find people who've either left or joined. First I find the indices of the names in the merged dataframe that aren't in `df_1` or aren't in `df_2`:

```
def get_names_not_in_df(orig_df, merged_df):

    f_names_in_df_1 = merged_df["F_name"].isin(orig_df["F_name"])
    l_names_in_df_1 = merged_df["L_name"].isin(orig_df["L_name"])

    names_not_in_df_1 = f_names_in_df_1 & l_names_in_df_1
    names_not_in_df_1_indices = names_not_in_df_1[~names_not_in_df_1].index

    return names_not_in_df_1_indices

names_not_in_df_1_indices = list(get_names_not_in_df(df_1, df_3))
names_not_in_df_2_indices = list(get_names_not_in_df(df_2, df_3))
```

Then I make new dataframes with those indices, get rid of redundant columns, and add a new column to these dataframes indicating whether the employee is new or left:

```
people_who_left = df_3.iloc[names_not_in_df_2_indices].reset_index(drop=True)

# Add new column
people_who_left.loc[:,'New_or_left'] = "Left"

# Remove redundant columns
people_who_left.drop(["Salary", "Phone_number"], axis=1, inplace=True)
people_who_left = people_who_left.rename(columns={"Old_salary":"Salary", "Old_phone_number":"Phone_number"})

people_who_joined = df_3.iloc[names_not_in_df_1_indices].reset_index(drop=True)

# Add new column
people_who_joined.loc[:,'New_or_left'] = "New"

# Remove redundant columns
people_who_joined.drop(["Old_salary", "Old_phone_number"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Finally, you can concatenate the above two dataframes to get all the people who do not exist in both `df_1` and `df_2`:

```
df_of_non_intersection = pd.concat((people_who_left, people_who_joined), axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Let me know if you have any questions.